# How to update guava for Selenium Standalone Server

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, guava

I had a working Code in Selenium.
After updating Geckodriver and the Selenium Standalone Server the Webdriver `wait.until()` function didn't work anymore.
So after using google I noticed I also have to update guava to version 23.
In eclipse I imported this guava version into the project but the function is still not available.
Does anyone has already experience with this problem or knows the solution?

Best Regards

Edit:

This is the ErrorMessage:

> The method until(Function) in the type
>   FluentWait is not applicable for the arguments
>   (Predicate)

But I don't actually use FluentWait. I use WebDriverWait

```
void waitForPageLoad(double d){
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(this.driver, 10);

    Predicate<WebDriver> pageLoaded = new Predicate<WebDriver>(){
        @Override
        public boolean apply(WebDriver input){
            return ((JavascriptExecutor) input).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete");
        }
    };
    try {
        Thread.sleep((long) (d*1000));
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    wait.until(pageLoaded);
}
```

Comment: btw I imported guava as Library to the Java Build Path

Comment: What class are you referring to?

Comment: the class should be FluentWait.java I think

Comment: It surely is there in 2.35 version: http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-support/2.35.0/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.java#FluentWait.until%28com.google.common.base.Function%29

Comment: Please update with what error are you getting?

Comment: And it the latest version as well: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void waitForPageLoad(double d){
        try {
            Thread.sleep((long) (d*1000));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        new WebDriverWait(this.driver, (long) (10000)).until(driver -> 
                ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete"));
    }
```

I found this solution and it's working. So there is no more need to update Guava manually. They simply changed something in their Framework